# Objective-c program crashes when trying to remove objects from superview

Tags: ios, xcode, view, crash, superview

Bellow is the code i am calling when i press a button. The button will call the method bellow. But i get a  "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. What am i doing wrong? The objects have been declared in another method before this one is called. I have also tried hiding the buttons but they also crash. Someone please help.

```
-(void) clearControlPannel{

    [buttCheck removeFromSuperview];
    [buttBet removeFromSuperview];
    [buttCall removeFromSuperview];
    [buttRaise removeFromSuperview];
    [buttFold removeFromSuperview];
    [betLabel removeFromSuperview];
    [betSlider removeFromSuperview];

}
```

The crash is:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the [buttCheck removeFromSuper]; line

> -[__NSCFDictionary removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686b020 2012-06-24 19:08:12.175 
>   HeadsUp[59630:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686b020'

Comment: what is the crash report you're getting?

Comment: I believe a better question would be: What line is Xcode saying this is crashing one?

Comment: Is the crash related to calling `clearControlPanel` or `removeFromSuperview` ?

Comment: -[__NSCFDictionary removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686b020
2012-06-24 19:08:12.175 HeadsUp[59630:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x686b020'

Comment: It crashes on the removeFromSuperview line. I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the [buttCheck removeFromSuper]; line.

Comment: Could we see some other details? Are you using a dictionary for a specific reason? A dictionary hasn't a `removeFromSuperview` method. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unrecognized selector sent to instance

error is due to the fact that the runtime is not able to find the method that will respond to that specific action. In other words, it's not able to map the name of your method (the selector) with its implementation.

So, if you have a method that accept no parameter like yours

```
- (void) clearControlPannel {...}
```

the selector will be only `clearControlPannel`.

Otherwise, if you have specified a parameter for that method (e.g. like the sender, the `UIButton` in this case) like

```
- (void) clearControlPannel:(id)sender {...}
```

the selector would be `clearControlPannel:`. Pay attention to `:`.

If you provide more details we could help you.

**EDIT**

Just for pointing you in the right direction.

If you have used `– addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` on a `UIButton` instance you have to check two things.

First, did you set up the `target` correctly? The `target` is the object to which the action will be redirected.

Second, did you set up the right selector for that `action`?

Here an example:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action@selector(mySelector:) ...];
```

where

```
- (void)mySelector:(id)sender {...}
```

If the class where you have implemented that button will also respond to that action use `self`, otherwise you need to inject some other instance that will respond for that action.

Comment: I do not send it a parameter, [buttCall addTarget:self action:@selector(call) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; Then inside the "call" method there is a [self clearControlPannel];

Comment: I have also realised that if i comment out the buttons (objects starting with variable name 'butt') then it does not crash, which suggests it is a problem with the UIButtons.

Answer (score -1):

Check wheather you are releasing the button which you are pressing.

Comment: Should i be releasing the button?